# Use string as input in Keras IMDB example

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, keras, tensorflow-serving

I was looking at the [Keras IMDB Movie reviews sentiment classification example](https://keras.io/datasets/#imdb-movie-reviews-sentiment-classification) ([and the corresponding model on github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py)), which learns to decide whether a review is positive or negative.

The data has been preprocessed such that each review is encoded as a sequence of integers, e.g. the review "This movie is awesome!" would be `[11, 17, 6, 1187]` and for this input the model gives the output 'positive'.

The dataset also makes available the word index used for encoding the sequences, i.e. I know the map

```
This: 11
movie: 17
is: 6
awesome: 1187
...
```

Can I somehow include this knowledge into the model such that its input is a string, i.e. it gives a prediction based on the input "This movie is awesome!"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First up, the input to the neural network is never a string, it's exactly a list of indices of words (or characters) in a vocabulary. And the first thing the model usually does is embedding transformation (see [the example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py)) which further converts these indices into the (trainable) float vectors.

What you really mean is *data pre-processing* step that transforms the raw input from the user (can be text, image pixels, sound recording, etc) into a format that is suitable and convenient for the model. Data pre-processing is an essential part of the machine-learning application just like the model itself, and should be stored separately. If you intend to work with imdb dataset, the vocabulary is already pre-processed. You can call `imdb.get_word_index()` in keras to get the word index or you can work with the [vocabulary json file](https://s3.amazonaws.com/text-datasets/imdb_word_index.json) directly.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping for something like the [categorical vocabulary column](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/categorical_column_with_vocabulary_file), so that I can serve the model in Google Cloud ML Engine and just send strings there.

Comment: If you look what `tf.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_file` is doing, it's the same: the vocab file must be stored separately and the feature column is transforming the input to int index. The difference is in responsibility for the pre-processing step. Anyway, keras doesn't provide similar functionality.